# Change String Array Item to Bold in Android

Tags: android, arrays

I have lots of String Array in my app that I am currently working. I am calling those String-array in my ListViews. I want to change certain String in my String Array Item into Bold. I already used Html.fromHtml() and "<[DATA[ ]]>" but it nothing's happening. How can I do that?

String.java

```
<string-array name="procedure_items">
    <item>• State: This is an emergency </item>
    <item>• Give the dispatcher:</item>
    <item>\t    •  The nature of emergency</item>
    <item>\t    •  Your name</item>
    <item>\t    •  Phone number from which you are calling</item>
    <item>\t    •  Your location/location of the emergency</item>
</string-array>
```

items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</TextView>
```

mainActivity.java

```
private void populateListView() {
    String[] myItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.procedure_items);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.items, myItems);

    // Configure the list view.
    lv_procedures.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

When called, the Output must be:

• State: "**This is an emergency**"

• Give the dispatcher:

- **The nature of emergency**
- **Your name**
- **Phone number from which you are calling**
- **Your location/location of the emergency**

Comment: Remove the text effects (`setTypeface()`, `setTextSize()`, `setTextColor()`) and see what happens. Also, you may need to post layout/items.xml source for us to fully understand your code.

Comment: Removing text effects did not help?

Comment: @shoe rat, yes, it didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `<b> </b>` tag for bold and escape the double quotes symbol with `\`:

```
<string-array name="procedure_items">
    <item>• State: <b>\"This is an emergency\"</b></item>
    <item>• Give the dispatcher:</item>
    <item>\t    •  <b>The nature of emergency</b></item>
    <item>\t    •  <b>Your name</b></item>
    <item>\t    •  <b>Phone number from which you are calling</b></item>
    <item>\t    •  <b>Your location/location of the emergency</b></item>
</string-array>
```

And use [`getTextArray()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getTextArray%28int%29) instead of `getStringArray()` as the latter will strip out styled text information. So, an example class would look like as follows:

```
package com.example.stringarraybolditem;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.items, getResources()
                .getTextArray(R.array.procedure_items)));
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: String Array Bold Item]

---

### Below is original `ListPreference` implementation

`ListPreference` items with `<b></b>` tags:

[image: ListPreference with items with bold effect]

And the corresponding `ListPreference`, res/xml/bold_item_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/procedure_items"
        android:entryValues="@array/procedure_items_values"
        android:title="@string/bold_item_test" />
    
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: should I use Html.fromHtml() in my activity?

Comment: For bold effect? No, not necessarily needed.

Comment: Please see above question. Thanks.

Comment: @TwistedDroid I did not use any Java code, that's just a ListPreference (xml)

Comment: You didn't use any adapter? Coz I used arrayAdapter in my above code. Then, how can I access/call the ListPreference (bold_item_test.xml)?

Comment: By the way, there should not have Radio Buttons in the ListView. Only the texts themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom cell and put a conditional statement to put whatever format is required for the control that holds that text/string.

here is a good one for using custom cells in android:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/